# Argue for or against that the Fourier series for the function $f(x) = 6x+2$ converges pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the function $f \in C_{st}$ that satisfies that
$$
f(x) = 6x+2
$$
Then I have to argue for or against that the Fourier series for $f$ converges pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have said that as $f(x)$ is a well-known continuous function we can calculate 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi^-} 6x+2 = 6\pi + 1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow -\pi^+} 6x+2 = -6\pi + 1
$$
Thus $f$ is continuous at $\pm \pi$ and $f(\pi) = 6\pi + 1$ and $f(-\pi) = -6\pi +1$. But doesn't this mean that $f$ is not $2\pi$ periodic? It just does not make sense to me as one of the criteria for being a function in $C_{st}$ is indeed that the function $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic.

Thus as $f$ is not $2\pi $-periodic, $f$ does not converge either pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Is this correct? But how can $f$ be in $C_{st}$ then?

Comment: The answer will depend on what $C_{st}$ means; I don't think it's a standard notation.

Comment: Ok I did not know it wasn't standard notation. This is the definition in my book: Let $C_{st}$ be the set of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies that: 1. f is $2 \pi$ periodic, 2. f is piecewise continuous on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. 3 f is normalized in its point of discontinuation meaning $f(x) = \frac{f(x_ )+f(x_+)}{2}$

Comment: The equation $f(x)=6x+2$ in the question must have been intended only for $-\pi<x<\pi$, because otherwise $f\notin C_{st}$. With this understanding of the question, you're right; the discontinuity at $\pm\pi$ prevents uniform convergence.

Comment: Yes, that is true it is for $-\pi < x < \pi$. I forgot to write that. But how can $f \in C_{st}$ when $f$ is not $2 \pi$ periodic?

Comment: If the equation $f(x)=6x+2$ is assumed only for $x$ in the interval $(=\pi,\pi)$, then there is a unique way to define $f(x)$ outside that interval to make it $2\pi$-periodic and to satisfy the normalization (3) in the definition of $C_{st}$. That's the $f$ that the question meant to ask about.

Comment: So it is correct to say that as $f(x) = 6x+2$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$ is not $2\pi$-periodic, the Fourier series for $f$ does not converge pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What would it even mean for a function defined only on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ to be $2\pi$-periodic? The only way I can see to make sense of it is to talk instead about the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function to be defined on all of $\mathbb R$. So I assume that's what's meant in the question.